# Is it possible exclude an entry type from result of craft.entries?

Tags: entries

I would like to fetch all entries apart from those of a specific type: 'chapter'. How do I achieve this with a standard call to 'craft.entries'?

```
{% set results = craft.entries({
  'search': query,
  'order': 'score'
}) %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going through Craft's docs, I found no easy or official way to do this. Fastest possible way, in my opinion:

```
{# get all section IDs #}
{% set sections = craft.sections.getAllSections() %}

{# get all entry types for sections #}
{% set entryTypes = [] %}
{% for section in sections %}
    {# exclude the entry type you don't want, add the others to 'entryTypes' variable
       you could, of course, replace handle by ID or whatever you like #}
    {% for entryType in section.getEntryTypes() if entryType.handle != 'handleToExclude' %}
        {% set entryTypes = entryTypes | merge([entryType]) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('inhoud').type(entryTypes) %}
```

Comment: This is what I tried but it doesn't work—I get 0 results.

Comment: Could you show me your code?

Comment: Exactly as you have it there, I get no results.

Comment: Did you replace `entryTypeHandle` with your entry type's handle?

Comment: Of course. Also, if I specify a type it works fine, just the 'not' bit seems to break things.

Comment: Ok. You got me there. My solution doesn't work, and after diving into Crafts code I know why: the `type` criterium does not accept 'not'. It only accepts a string containing the entry type's handle, an Int with the entry type's id or an entryTypeModel. Or an array containing one or more of those. Let me think about the best way to work around this for a moment.

Comment: Edited my answer, and tested the solution. It works on my side.

Comment: Weird isn't it? Could well be a bug.

Comment: Or a missing feature ;)

Comment: Bump, missing feature. The not clause works on other fields but not the type field. :(

Comment: Works for me in Craft 3 with the following modification: `merge([entryType.handle])`

Answer (score 2):

If anyone lands on this page same as I did, the far far simpler way to do this is just to include the .type() method and combine it with the 'not' word:

```
{% set results = craft.entries({
  'search': query,
  'type': 'not chapter',
  'order': 'score'
}) %}
```

Comment: This is the correct modern answer to the OP

Answer (score 1):

You can target the entry by ID and tell it 'not' to include it. The example below will exclude the current entry page. You can replace "#{entry.id}" with the ID of the entry you want to exclude.

```
{% set results = craft.entries({
  'id': "not #{entry.id}",
  'search': query,
  'order': 'score'
}) %}
```

Comment: Sorry if unclear but I wish to exclude all entries of an entry type, not a single entry.