# How to exclude entries by type?

Tags: entries

I did find [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4796/is-it-possible-exclude-an-entry-type-from-result-of-craft-entries) while looking to do something similar, but I'm beginning to wonder if there's a bug.

With code along the lines of:

```
craft.entries.section("pages").type("not landing")
```

I'm unexpectedly getting no results. Looking at the logs, it's generating queries that includes:

```
SELECT * FROM `craft_entrytypes` `t` WHERE `t`.`handle`='not landing'
```

I have to think this is at least partly responsible for getting no results. Could anyone point out if I've got the syntax wrong or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.type("not landing")` won't work. If you reread the [post you linked](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4796/is-it-possible-exclude-an-entry-type-from-result-of-craft-entries) it also states this — I believe it was more of a feature request. You will need to test each entry and either use it directly or merge it into an array for later use.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section("pages") %}
{% for entry in entries if entry.type != "landing" %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% set filteredEntries = [] %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section("pages") %}
{% for entry in entries if entry.type != "landing" %}
    {% set filteredEntries = filteredEntries|merge(entry) %}
{% endfor %}
```

As a side note, if you are using a `structure` with a hierarchy where landing pages are at the root level and all other entries are children, then you can also use:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section("pages").level('> 1') %}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, seems I was assuming any parameter can be excluded using the not [syntax described in the docs here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax) - have I missed somewhere that lists when you can (e.g. `.id('not 123')`) and can't?

As for my specific example I was already just manually listing the other entry types which achieved the desired results.

Comment: Good point (and question). According to the docs you linked you would think that it should work. I'm not sure which parameters can use the "not" syntax.

Comment: For future reference, this (`.type("not landing")`) appears to be working fine in Craft CMS 3.1 _at least_.

Answer (score 4):

What about first getting all the landing page entries, and then use these entries' IDs prefixed with `'not'` (works with IDs!) in the ID param of a second ElementCriteriaModel.

```
{% set landingPageIds = craft.entries.section('pages').type('landing').ids() %}    
{% set idParam = 'and, not ' ~ landingPageIds|join(', not ') %}
{% set pagesWithoutLanding = craft.entries.section('pages').id(idParam) %}
```

Comment: ... witchcraft!