# Exclude entries

Tags: craft2

I want to use search but exclude some `types` but when I use

```
 paginate craft.entries({
     search: query
 }).type('not faq').limit(4).order('postDate desc') as pageInfo, results %}
```

`results` are always an empty array

when I remove `not` it search only in `faq` type.

I also try: `!faq`, `~faq`, `-faq`;

Comment: I think that this may have been what you're looking for. https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/how-to-exclude-entries-by-type